# Trying to use php PDO update statement to update datas on my table by id

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to update my database table with php PDO update statement which update the table by an already existing id.

```php
if (isset($_POST["save"])) {
  $id = $_POST["save"];
  $my_editor = $_POST["my_editor"];
  $sql = 'UPDATE advert_composer SET content = :content WHERE id = 1';
  $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(['my_editor' => $my_editor, 'id' => $id ]);

  if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Content created successfully'];
  } else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = ['type' => 'info', 'message' => 'Error Occured Creating Content Try again later'];
  } 
}
```

This is the error I'm getting.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/ubth_recruit/admin/advert_composer.php:16 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/ubth_recruit/admin/advert_composer.php(16):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/ubth_recruit/admin/advert_composer.php on line 16

Comment: `my_editor` != `content` - you are binding `:content` in the query, but try to execute a bind to `my_editor`. Then, your ID is static (assigned to 1  in the query) and you attempt to bind it in the execute.

Comment: You are trying to bind ID when you have already set this  as 1 in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query only contains 1 parameter (`:content`).

```
$sql = 'UPDATE advert_composer SET content = :content  WHERE id = 1';
```

Either change `:content` to `:my_editor`, or the other way round.

Another reason – as was mentioned in the comments – is the `id` has a fixed value (1). You should either change the `1` to `:id`, or remove the ID from the `execute()` array.

---

This explains why you get the exception:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in (...)

Simply because the amount of available parameters (only 1 in your case, starting with `:`) in your query does not match the given amount of arguments (2 given) in `execute()`.